# how to push view controller from a UIView's subclass

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I created a view "`CategoryTableView`" that subclass from `UIView`. And `CategoryTableView` contains a `UITableView`. I added `CategoryTableView` as a subview to `HomeViewController` that subclass from `UIViewController`. Right now, I want to push a new view controller when `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` executes. But, in  `CategoryTableView`, how do I push or present another view controller. I can't get to the navigation controller in `CategoryTableView`.

Comment: You don't. Redesign your code.

Comment: Done. I am using delegate, and I can push to new view controller now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**CategoryTableView.h**

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) parentViewController *parent; //create one property for parent view like this
```

**CategoryTableView.m**

```
@sythesize parent;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [parent.navigationController . . .]; // preform action
    //OR..
    [parent presentModalViewController: . . .]; // present modal view
}
```

**parent.m**

```
//while calling your CategoryTableView assign self to your parent object

    CategoryTableView *tblView = [CategoryTableView alloc] init];
    tblView.parent = self;
```

Comment: If parentViewController is in stack of UINaviagationController then its valid code.

Comment: Thanks, it works too. Your method is better than I plan to use delegate method.

Comment: This works, but it's bad practice. UIViews aren't supposed to have direct access to the navcon as it breaks MVC. Breaking MVC doesn't mean that the code will fail, but what it does mean is that you'll end up with spaghetti code where it's not clear what each class's job is, and on a large project the code will become indecipherable. A UIView is supposed to be just a view, presenting visuals but not controlling any app logic. That's a controller's job. That's why you should make your UIViewController a delegate which receives a message from your UIView and performs the navigation logic itself.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use custom delegates to achieve this...

in **CategoryTableView.h**

```
@protocol CategoryTableViewDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)pushViewControllerUsinDelegate:(UIViewController *)viewController;

@end

@interface CategoryTableView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, retain) id<CategoryTableViewDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

in **CategoryTableView.m**

@implementation CategoryTableView

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Create the required UIViewControllers instance and call the delegate method.
    UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [self.delegate pushViewControllerUsinDelegate:viewController];
}


@end
```

in **HomeViewController.h**

```
 @interface HomeViewController : UIViewController <CategoryTableViewDelegate>

    @end
```

in **HomeViewController.m**

```
@implementation HomeViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //initialization of CategoryTableView like this...
    CategoryTableView *categoryTableViewInstance = [[CategoryTableView alloc] init];
    [categoryTableViewInstance setDelegate:self];

}

-(void)pushViewControllerUsinDelegate:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```