# iOS how present Modal ViewController from Uiview

Tags: ios, uiview

i have subclass a `UIView` and now i need to show a view controller but `UIView` not have method to present view controller.
this is my problem
thank's

this is a piece of code inside my uiview subclass

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if ([tabella isEqualToString:@"Articoli"]) {
        NSDictionary *itm=(NSDictionary*)[comanda objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        Articoli *aboutViewController = [[Articoli alloc] initWithNibName:@"Articoli" bundle:nil];

        aboutViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
        aboutViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
        aboutViewController.idarticolo=[itm objectForKey:@"idarticolo"];
        CGRect aboutSheetFrame = aboutViewController.view.frame;

        UIViewController *viewController = [UIViewController new];
        viewController.view = self;

        //here xcode give me a red error
        [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil] ;

        aboutSheetFrame =CGRectZero;
        aboutViewController.view.superview.bounds = aboutSheetFrame;

    }
}
```

Comment: please share some piece of code...

Comment: the problem is that i don't know to display a view controller from uiview subclass.

Comment: Well this is not a new questions. take a look at this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15779485/how-to-push-view-controller-from-a-uiviews-subclass

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you need a communication between `UIView` instance and `UIViewController`, there are a few known iOS concepts, which you should adhere to. As you have figured out that `UIView` cannot really present a new controller (missing either `presetViewController:animated:completion` methods or `navigationController` property, which are both present in `UIViewController`).

Views are supposed to be the most reusable parts of your code, so you must think of a way to design your views to be completely blind to where they are at. They usually only know about user interaction.

**So first, what you must do is refactor your view.**

1. If your `UIView` is supposed to be a `UIControl` (has some kind of target selectors), you need to use add target in your controller to get callback from view interaction.
2. You can use delegate pattern as used in `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`, which is designed as a protocol.
3. You can use gesture recognizers added to a view (`UITapGestureRecognizer` for example), so the controller knows about user interaction.

You can even mix and match those architectural patterns.

But you should **really look** into iOS programming basics, to understand this better.

In addition the **first error** I see in your code is that you create a generic `UIViewController`, when you should really be creating custom subclasses of it, defined in Storyboard and separate subclass of `UIViewController`.

The second error I see is that your `UIView` responds do `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, which should in fact **never** happen. All this code must be moved back to one `UIViewController` subclass.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this without any view hierarchy issues using the below code.

**ObjectiveC**

```
UIViewController *currentTopVC = [self currentTopViewController];
currentTopVC.presentViewController......... 

- (UIViewController *)currentTopViewController
{
    UIViewController *topVC = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
    while (topVC.presentedViewController)
    {
        topVC = topVC.presentedViewController;
    }
    return topVC;
}
```

**Swift**

```
var topVC = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController
while((topVC!.presentedViewController) != nil){
     topVC = topVC!.presentedViewController
}
topVC?.presentViewController........
```

Comment: Is this still a valid answer 7 years later? Swift 5

Answer (score 3):

`PresentViewController` is method of `UIViewController` class not of `UIView`, you can do one thing, create `UIViewController` instance and set its view to the view you have and then present it.
Something like below

```
YourCustomView *customView = [[YourCustomView alloc]initWithFrame:someFrame];

UIViewController *viewController = [UIViewController new];
viewController.view = customView;

//From currentViewController present this 
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil] ;
```

Customize this code as per your requirement

But as you are in view you need to pass this event to viewController, so better implement delegate method and at place where you calling present viewController call delegate which is implemented in ViewController and in side that presentViewController with customView set to its view property

Comment: ok whit your code i have make right, now if you see my code on top i want to present in form sheet. thank's

Answer (score 2):

**You can also present your viewcontroller from the navigation controller object**

Create Global Navigation Object in App Delegate or anywhere, you can access navigationcontroller object from view

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *gblNavigation;
```

//Present viewcontroller from NavigationController object

```
[gblNavigation presentViewController:YOUR_VC_Object animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't present a view controller from a view. You can only present a view controller from a view controller.

Apple wants views to be dumb. That is views should only know how to display content. View should not respond to user interaction: that should be passed to a view controller.

You may want to consider using a delegate pattern, target action, or something similar to allow a view controller to control the interaction.

Answer (score -1):

**iOS 15, compatible down to iOS 13**

Based on Shamsudheen TK solution for anyone who comes across this question in the future.

```swift
let presentedWindow = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.flatMap { ($0 as? UIWindowScene)?.windows ?? [] }.first { $0.isKeyWindow }
guard let currentViewController = presentedWindow?.rootViewController else {
  return
}
currentViewController.present(UIViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil), animated: true)
```

**Note** that connectedScenes is available only since iOS 13. If you need to support earlier versions of iOS, you have to place this in an if #available(iOS 13, *) statement.

Comment: Per the Model-View-Controller design pattern a view should never present a view controller. Instead the proper way would be to have a delegate callback for the view. The view controller that owns this view would implement the delegate callback and then present the next view controller.