# Programatically create segue from xib file to viewcontroller in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, xib

I use a library which has a xib file in objective-c

I have my storyboard that has swift classes

I need to create segue from that xib file to my storyboard and pass some data.

Tried this with no luck

**XIB File**

```
#import "IncomingMessageCell.h"

@implementation IncomingMessageCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {

    UIImage * balloonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bubble-left"];
    balloonImage = [balloonImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets){36, 32, 18, 12}];
    self.bubbleView.image = balloonImage;

    self.avatarView.layer.cornerRadius = 25;
    self.avatarView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    self.avatarView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(tapGesture:)];

    tapGesture1.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

    [tapGesture1 setDelegate:self];

    [self.avatarView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture1];
    }

- (void) tapGesture: (id)sender
{
    UIViewController *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourVcIdentifier"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}


- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

How is that possible ?

Comment: where do you try this? and what is your current VC ?

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: so what happens when you tap ?

Comment: cannot build i get Property 'navigationController' not found on object of type 'IncomingMessageCell *' error

Comment: I see IncomingMessageCell is not of type UIVIewController. You need to have a delegate that holds the reference to navigation controller. How is IncomingMessageCell created ?

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15779485/how-to-push-view-controller-from-a-uiviews-subclass

Comment: @TejaNandamuri thanks but i still don't understand how to do that.

Comment: please provide info of how and where IncomingMEssageCell is initialised.

Comment: UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"IncomingMessageCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.tableView registerNib:cellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"IncomingMessageCell"];

Answer (score 0):

Do like this in ViewController that holds tableview with this cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    IncomingMessageCell *cell = ...;
    cell.avatarView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
   [cell.avatarView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    cell.avatarView.tag = 500 + indexPath.row;  // To detect cell that image belongs to, because you use dequeue cell
    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)handleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture{
    //Do you action
    NSLog(@"Row tap : %ld",tapGesture.view.tag - 500);
    UIViewController *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourVcIdentifier"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I can handle the click already but i don't know how to segue to main storyboard

Comment: Yes, but to handle segue, you should put your code in ViewController not in Cell. 
Try my way, you can put your code that push to another view :

`- (IBAction)handleCellBtnClicked:(UIButton *)sender{
    //Do you action
UIViewController *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourVcIdentifier"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}`

Comment: cant we use tabgesture from cellForRowAtIndexPath ?

Comment: you dont have to use tapgesture in cellForRow method. You can use didSelectRow method@UtkuDalmaz

Comment: @TejaNandamuri i don't wanna use whole cell for segue, i just need uiimageview

Comment: If you only want to push to another ViewController when user clicks at UIImage, you can should use like my way, it is easier than create tapGesture for each UIImageView ( because 1 tapGesture is only used for 1 view) .
If you want to push to another VC when user clicks at row, you can add function pushSegue to method 
`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: But you can do with tapGesture

Comment: @matiboo can you also show an example with tabgestıre in cellforrow?

Comment: @UtkuDalmaz Oke, i will edit my answer. Please wait a min

Comment: @UtkuDalmaz please check my new answer. And if it is right, close this question :D

Comment: @matiboo iam still having Property 'navigationController' not found on object of type 'PopupChatView *' error :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110415/discussion-between-utku-dalmaz-and-matiboo).